# Optimize three.js for a large mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I'm working on a project where I have around 59k points, and each point should be represented as a cube in three.js.

I have it combining all the geometries together, into one mesh so that it improves performance, but It is still pretty slow (around 10-30 fps).

How can I improve this? For this project it's only acceptable to have it running smoothly (say around 40-60 fps), so I really need some improvements.

Here is my code that creates the mesh and scene:

```
function init() {

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);

camera.position.set(230.09813315369976, 233.67707474083232, -181.06937619976165);
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

THREE.currentCamera = camera;

if (controlsEnabled) {
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
    controls.damping = 0.2;
}
scene = new THREE.Scene();

geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000, wireframe: false});
console.log("Adding " + locations.length + " voxels");

var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

$.each(locations, function (index, value) {
    geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);

    matrix.makeTranslation(
            value['x'],
            0,
            value['y']
            );

    geometry.merge(geo, matrix);
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(100);
scene.add(axes);
camera.lookAt(mesh);
raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
var element = renderer.domElement;
document.getElementById('page-wrapper').appendChild(renderer.domElement);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
var flag = 0;
element.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
    flag = 0;
}, false);
element.addEventListener("mousemove", function () {
    flag = 1;
}, false);
element.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
    if (flag === 0) {
        console.log("click");
        doRaycast = true;
    }
    else if (flag === 1) {
        console.log("drag");
    }
}, false);
$('#loading-vis').hide();
animate();
```

}

Comment: theoretically, 59k x 12 tris per cube isn't that bad. I'm not sure what happens under the hood when you merge all of that into a single geometry.  

Without getting into too much detail, can you create an array instead of your geometry, divide your 59k points into say, 20 groups, (each 59k/20 steps, push the resulting merged geometry into the array, and start merging the next batch into a new geometry). Make 20 different meshes for each resulting geometry and see if it helps.

Comment: @pailhead I was under the impression that the less meshes you have, the faster it will run?

Comment: its a wild guess, but i was thinking that there might be an issue when addressing a mesh that has more than 65535 triangles. I haven't played with indexed buffered geometry. What i do know though, is that this amount of triangles, should not render at 10 fps if its set up correctly. And an easy way to set it up 'correctly' with your code is to do what i suggested.

Comment: That did it! wow I didn't think that would fix it xD If you convert your comment to an answer I'll mark it correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is true that batching the geometry into as few draw calls as possible is an optimization, it's not exactly that straightforward.

I can't exactly explain what goes on under the hood, but the safest and easiest way is to issue a draw call that has less than 65536 triangles (2^16) in a so called "triangle soup".

What happened was you batched everything into one geometry, but under the hood either something messy happened with the indexed geometry, or somehow the geometry wa broken back into fewer pieces.

The solution was not to batch everything into one geom, but multiple, each having less than 65536 triangles.